# MICE_Memory error_IterativeImputer_for missing values Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

While implementing iterative imputer in python, I am getting memory error.
Iterative imputer in python (similar to implementation of MICE technique in R) considers each missing value in a row as a dependent variable and all the other features in that row as independent variables. Then it applies regression on the independent variables and computes the missing value of the dependent variable in every row. So rather than replacing missing values with mean, median etc., missing values are filled with synthetic values using regression technique

**X_train**

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 ...........Col100
```

X_train has 100 columns, with 250k rows.

**Code**

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
# now you can import normally from sklearn.impute
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge
import random

imputer = IterativeImputer(BayesianRidge())
impute_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(X_train))
```

**Error**

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-4b5dc3d8a845> in <module>
      1 imputer = IterativeImputer(BayesianRidge())
----> 2 impute_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(X_train))
```

I am getting memory error while implementing IterativeImputer

**Environment**

- Python 3.7
- Jupyter notebooks
- Anaconda Navigator
- Lenovo 8GB RAM Laptop
- intel CORE i5 8th gen processor.
- GPU not being used (scikit does not support GPU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use IterativeImputer , then at times the memory is not sufficient in Jupyter notebook etc. to handle all the columns data specially if data is huge. So the way to implement iterative imputer in such cases is by breaking down the data into manageable chunks.

```
imputer = IterativeImputer(BayesianRidge())
```

Divide data into subsets:

```
subset1=X_train[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3',...'Col10']]
subset2=X_train[['Col1', 'Col11', 'Col12',...'Col20']]  #assuming col1 is key column
and so on till Col100 is reached

impute_data_subset1 = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(subset1))
impute_data_subset2 = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(subset2))
impute_data_subset3 = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(subset3))
```

and so on and later join the data

```
subset_1_to_2= pd.merge(impute_data_subset1,impute_data_subset2, on='Col1')
subset_1_to_3= pd.merge(impute_data_subset3, subset_1_to_2,on='Col1')
subset_1_to_4= pd.merge(impute_data_subset4, subset_1_to_3,on='Col1')

.........
subset_1_to_10 = pd.merge(impute_data_subset9, subset_1_to_9,on='Col1')
```

and so on

subset_1_to_10 contains the total imputed dataframe which you can directly use.

Comment: Hi, does the imputer also use 'Col1' also for imputation? What if 'Col1' is my ID for patients? Also, in this case, how do we use the same imputer for test data?